# How to Hide the Gridview specific positions based on conditions

Tags: android, arraylist

I am passing arraylist, which contains integer values, After checking some conditions I want to hide the previous values present in the arraylist how to achieve this one. If anyone knows please help me to resolve this.

Comment: show your code for better help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View v = gridview.getChildAt(ChildPosition);
v.setVisibility(GONE);
```

Comment: how will u use this code because that arraylist iam passing to the grid adapter..where can i use this??either in fragment or adapter

Answer (score 0):

Before the attach the value to the control (setText etc.) in get view method remove that specific position or if you have specific position like you want to hide 5 number position from ArrayList than trying like

here check this condition inside  get view method

```
if(!(position == 5))
{
    mTextView.setText(String.values(bean.getValues));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final BookingSlotTimeAdapter bookingSlotTimeAdapter = new BookingSlotTimeAdapter(getActivity(), stringArrayList, 1);
        moringGridSlot.setAdapter(bookingSlotTimeAdapter);
```

This way I am passing `arraylist` to `adapter`. I am checking current time as a string if current time less than passing arraylist values disable the previous times of the arraylist values.